# "moment is not defined" using moment.js

Tags: javascript, time, momentjs

I am working with moment.js, but as I am testing the moment.js library I continue to receive an error.

```
var back30Days=moment().subtract(30, 'days').format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss p");
```

it returns "`moment not defined.`" referring to `.format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss p");`

I've read the documentation, and everything looks fine, but when I reload my page, the js I'm working with won't load.

any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How are you importing the library? Post your code, please.

Comment: seemed to work ok for  me.   https://jsfiddle.net/vbgdke3L/

Comment: i downloaded the library, and is included in my index.html under script, and using cdn, too.

Comment: @alej_dra have you tried my solution? use only cdn see if it is working, make sure moment.js is loaded before you use it.

Comment: I did, and got the same error. trying another code...

Comment: got it to work, thanks daniel! my scripts where out of order!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

With latest momentjs:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

```js
var back30Days=moment().subtract(30, 'days').format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss p");

console.log('back30Days --> ' + back30Days);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I am getting same error when refreshing the page. but not at first time when page load

Comment: @PawanKotak you can download the lib to your project and use it. Sometime if you have a lib that also using momentjs, it could be an old version and overwrite your own momentjs, try to print `moment.version` see what you get?

Comment: I tried including lib in project but still same issue. Tried printing version but error "moment is not defined". And even when I am trying to include Moment.js again dynamically using $getscript it calling success callback and inside that when I am trying to access moment same issue

Comment: @PawanKotak "moment is not defined" your reference didn't work so lib not loaded, common issue, try debug that, 1. hard clean cache. 2. call moment right after the `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>` and see what happened.

Comment: For those of you who are like me, and scratch your head because you weren't paying attention. Verify that you are using the above CDNs for MomentJs core NOT a standalone locale. CDNJs threw me off 'cause I'm used to just going, copy, paste. Well /Moment.Js on their site hosts the locales instead.

Comment: Will this cdn work for react application? I am getting moment is not defined.